# Custom Loading Cursor

Tags: html, css, web, cursor

I want to know if there is a way to change the "progress" cursor's loading animation. Like changing the cursor like in this [CSS-Trick](https://css-tricks.com/using-css-cursors/) post.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to achieve what you want.

**The CSS way**

If you want to completely customize the cursor, you can use `cursor` which accept images (in your case, a .gif !)

```
._show-loader:hover {
  cursor: url('http://i117.photobucket.com/albums/o72/redfenderstrat/Debian_Rotate.gif');
}
```

I like this approach since I prefer keeping JS out of my pure design things as much as possible.

**The jQuery way**

If you need to add an animation after user's cursor (to make this more natural since people does not have the same cursor), this jQuery alternative will make the image stick to the cursor.

```
var $showLoader = $('._show-loader');

$showLoader.on('mousemove', function(e) {
  var cursorPos = {
    left: e.pageX + 20,
    top: e.pageY + 20,
  }

  $("._cursor-onLoad").css({
    left: cursorPos.left,
    top: cursorPos.top
  });
});

$showLoader.on('mouseenter', function() {
  $('._cursor-onLoad').css({
    display: 'block',
  })
});

$showLoader.on('mouseleave', function() {
  $('._cursor-onLoad').css({
    display: 'none',
  })
});
```

[JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/BfLAh/3001/)

I doesn't really like this alternative since it does this 2002-sluggish effect.

Comment: This is somewhat of what I want. But I want to change the blue circle. For instance when the page is loading. What I want is to have the Mac loading animation. [Click here for Pic](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/7e/OS_X_10.11_Beta_Beach_Ball.jpg)

Comment: The Mac animation is the "Mac" animation because you're on a mac. On Windows, you'll have the "Windows animation". This is a native behavior so if you want to change the Mac animation, you may download a .gif of this animation, custom it, then try one of solution above

Comment: But the example above is just adding another animation, instead of replacing the windows animation. I want to know if I can replace this on my website.